# Отправка фото админу телеграм

Tags: telegram, бот, aiogram

Подскажите пожалуйста как отправлять фото админу через бота.Пример моего кода:else:
await bot.send_photo(chat_id=ADMIN,photo=message.photo)

Comment: photo=message.photo[-1] и дело в шляпе

Comment: Спасибо  так просто было .

Comment: @oleksandrigo подскажите пожалуйста можно ли как-то писать от имени бота , если можно то можешь скинуть пожалуйста код